# How to get the length of a page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just started to do some Wordpress Theme Coding.

I would like to integrate a feature in my theme which integrates another  element depending on the length of my page entry (content).

The Idea was to say

```
if( div with content >= 310 px ) {
  <div id="">
  </div>
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [jQuery integrated](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAIjzUkWX8s&feature=fvwrel) you can just use

```
$('#div_to_check').height();
```

or for the whole document

```
$(document).height();
```

similar to

```
<script> 
    if( $('#div_to_check').height() >= 310) {    
        document.write('<div id=""></div>');
    }
</script>
```

Because the content of your page will most likely be variable, you'll need to check the height after the page finishes loading, so I'd definitely do this via Javascript and not attempt it with PHP.